# Elastic Beanstalk hosted React Application - Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I recently pushed a new build onto elastic beanstalk and ran into the syntax error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

[image: Error in Firefox]

[image: Error in Chrome]

Here is how i'm serving the build using express:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client", "build")));
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./client/", "build/index.html"));
});
```

It seems index.html is being served since the DOM gets populated. When I revert back to my old build the issue disappears. To recreate, I run:

```
npm run-script build
git add .
git commit -m ""
eb deploy
```

Once the new build is deployed onto Elastic Beanstalk, the syntax error shows up. The issue also does not appear when I run my express server locally and test the new build.

I've been stuck on this issue for quite a while now, any input is appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Inspect your code. (Perhaps you committed a Git conflict marker, instead of resolving a conflict. Git itself isn't the issue though: you just have a bug in your JS code.)

Comment: Tried clearing your browser cache? It could have kept an old copy of `index.html` with the old `.js` files referenced

Comment: @torek If there was a glaring issue in the code like that, the build should also be broken while being served locally. This only crops up when hosted on elastic beanstalk.

Comment: @Phil I have tried it. The old .js actually work, it's when I create a new build and push it.

Comment: Curious. The name of the file suggests it was autogenerated by some minifier, perhaps there was a broken one out there for a bit?

Comment: @torek The file is generated by react when the build is created.